Realme GT Master: can't make or receive calls
My phone has the following issue: incoming calls don't come through (any attempt to call by other phones results in voicemail), and outgoing calls don't work either (the "Phone" app gets stuck on "Calling..." without even a single beep).
Mobile data and SMS do work and the signal is at maximum. I tried switching the SIM card with mine, but the problem persists on the phone.
I put the SIM in the second slot, but the problem remains the same.
I have disabled both VoLTE and 5G.I tried messing with APNs. I tried calling the emergency number, and it works, both with and without the SIM card. I uninstalled and reinstalled the updates for Google Dialer, and I also uninstalled and reinstalled Carrier Services (including the beta release). I have restarted the phone multiple times. I even updated to the latest version (Android 13), but the problem still is the same before and after the update.
Has anyone encountered a similar problem? How did you handle it?
Phone is a Realme GT Master RMX3363 with Android 13 and 5th of July 2024 security patches applied.
This is the output of adb logcat *:E (omitting the 4 left-most columns) when attempting to dial someone:
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER: Perflock resource /sys/class/devfreq/soc:qcom,llccbw/min_freq not supported
    E ANDR-PERF-RESOURCEQS: Failed to apply optimization [12, 0]
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER: Perflock resource /sys/class/devfreq/soc:qcom,llccbw/min_freq not supported
    E ANDR-PERF-RESOURCEQS: Failed to apply optimization [12, 0]
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E ANDR-PERF-LM: MetaMeter: handleAsync() 166: AdaptLaunch Invalid Async
    E ANDR-PERF-LM: MetaMeter: handleAsync() 166: AdaptLaunch Invalid Async
    E ANDR-PERF-LM: MetaMeter: handleAsync() 166: AdaptLaunch Invalid Async
    E ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER: Perflock resource SPECIAL_NODE - cpubw_hwmon_hyst_opt not supported
    E ANDR-PERF-RESOURCEQS: Failed to apply optimization [6, 3]
    E ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER: Perflock resource /sys/class/devfreq/soc:qcom,llccbw/bw_hwmon/sample_ms not supported
    E ANDR-PERF-RESOURCEQS: Failed to apply optimization [12, 3]
    E ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER: Perflock resource SPECIAL_NODE - llcbw_hwmon_hyst_opt not supported
    E ANDR-PERF-RESOURCEQS: Failed to apply optimization [12, 2]
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E OplusBracketLog: [OplusViewMirrorManager] updateHostViewRootIfNeeded, not support android.view.ViewRootImpl@d3293a
    E ANDR-PERF-LM: MetaMeter: handleAsync() 166: AdaptLaunch Invalid Async
    E ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER: Perflock resource SPECIAL_NODE - cpubw_hwmon_hyst_opt not supported
    E ANDR-PERF-RESOURCEQS: Failed to apply optimization [6, 3]
    E ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER: Perflock resource /sys/class/devfreq/soc:qcom,llccbw/bw_hwmon/sample_ms not supported
    E ANDR-PERF-RESOURCEQS: Failed to apply optimization [12, 3]
    E ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER: Perflock resource SPECIAL_NODE - llcbw_hwmon_hyst_opt not supported
    E ANDR-PERF-RESOURCEQS: Failed to apply optimization [12, 2]
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E IPCThreadState: attemptIncStrongHandle(209): Not supported
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SensorService: Required app irp, uid 10251, pid 17005
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER: Perflock resource SPECIAL_NODE - cpubw_hwmon_hyst_opt not supported
    E ANDR-PERF-RESOURCEQS: Failed to apply optimization [6, 3]
    E ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER: Perflock resource /sys/class/devfreq/soc:qcom,llccbw/bw_hwmon/sample_ms not supported
    E ANDR-PERF-RESOURCEQS: Failed to apply optimization [12, 3]
    E ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER: Perflock resource SPECIAL_NODE - llcbw_hwmon_hyst_opt not supported
    E ANDR-PERF-RESOURCEQS: Failed to apply optimization [12, 2]
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E OplusBracketLog: [OplusViewMirrorManager] updateHostViewRootIfNeeded, not support android.view.ViewRootImpl@8c253c0
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E cellularState[0]: - unhandledMessage: msg.what=7
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E Proxy : Unsupported message id 2003
    E Proxy : Unsupported message id 2003
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E msm8974_platform: platform_check_backend_tag_match: Invalid snd_device = voice-dmic-ef
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E EventRuleService[20111]: update error 20111 -8 : 配置项被删除停用
    E audio_hw_utils: audio_extn_utils_update_stream_app_type_cfg_for_usecase: app type cfg not supported for usecase type (2)
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E GestureMonitorController: updateGesturePhoneState no such gesture
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SELinux : avc: denied { find } for pid=3627 uid=1001 name=vendor.oplus.hardware.rpmh.IRpmh/default scontext=u:r:radio:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:hal_oplus_rpmh_aidl_service:s0 tclass=service_manager permissive=0
    E ModemAciService: rpm server is not available, update failed!
    E DialerMddCallerTagsConfigProvider: com.android.dialer.callertags.configprovider.mdd.MddCallerTagsConfigProvider.lambda$getTagConfigs$6:156 No file group for caller tags locale: it-IT [CONTEXT disable_client_error_logging=true ]
    E DialerMddCallerTagsConfigProvider: vlp: MEDIUM
    E DialerMddCallerTagsConfigProvider: at a.cc(PG:15)
    E DialerMddCallerTagsConfigProvider: at ebt.a(PG:574)
    E DialerMddCallerTagsConfigProvider: at vxl.a(PG:57)
    E DialerMddCallerTagsConfigProvider: at vwv.d(PG:3)
    E DialerMddCallerTagsConfigProvider: at vwx.run(PG:42)
    E DialerMddCallerTagsConfigProvider: at qmf.run(PG:3)
    E DialerMddCallerTagsConfigProvider: at vrk.run(PG:50)
    E DialerMddCallerTagsConfigProvider: at qbv.run(PG:166)
    E DialerMddCallerTagsConfigProvider: at qbv.run(PG:394)
    E DialerMddCallerTagsConfigProvider: at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
    E DialerMddCallerTagsConfigProvider: at qnh.run(PG:64)
    E ModemAciService: sendSettleObj2Statsd over!
    E cellularState[0]: - unhandledMessage: msg.what=4
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E OplusCustomizeRestrictionManagerService: getMobileDataMode error :s == null
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER: Perflock resource SPECIAL_NODE - cpubw_hwmon_hyst_opt not supported
    E ANDR-PERF-RESOURCEQS: Failed to apply optimization [6, 3]
    E ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER: Perflock resource /sys/class/devfreq/soc:qcom,llccbw/bw_hwmon/sample_ms not supported
    E ANDR-PERF-RESOURCEQS: Failed to apply optimization [12, 3]
    E ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER: Perflock resource SPECIAL_NODE - llcbw_hwmon_hyst_opt not supported
    E ANDR-PERF-RESOURCEQS: Failed to apply optimization [12, 2]
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER: Perflock resource SPECIAL_NODE - cpubw_hwmon_hyst_opt not supported
    E ANDR-PERF-RESOURCEQS: Failed to apply optimization [6, 3]
    E ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER: Perflock resource /sys/class/devfreq/soc:qcom,llccbw/bw_hwmon/sample_ms not supported
    E ANDR-PERF-RESOURCEQS: Failed to apply optimization [12, 3]
    E ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER: Perflock resource SPECIAL_NODE - llcbw_hwmon_hyst_opt not supported
    E ANDR-PERF-RESOURCEQS: Failed to apply optimization [12, 2]
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E DialerMddCallerTagsConfigProvider: com.android.dialer.callertags.configprovider.mdd.MddCallerTagsConfigProvider.lambda$getTagConfigs$6:156 No file group for caller tags locale: it-IT [CONTEXT disable_client_error_logging=true ]
    E DialerMddCallerTagsConfigProvider: vlp: MEDIUM
    E DialerMddCallerTagsConfigProvider: at a.cc(PG:15)
    E DialerMddCallerTagsConfigProvider: at ebt.a(PG:574)
    E DialerMddCallerTagsConfigProvider: at vxl.a(PG:57)
    E DialerMddCallerTagsConfigProvider: at vwv.d(PG:3)
    E DialerMddCallerTagsConfigProvider: at vwx.run(PG:42)
    E DialerMddCallerTagsConfigProvider: at qmf.run(PG:3)
    E DialerMddCallerTagsConfigProvider: at vrk.run(PG:50)
    E DialerMddCallerTagsConfigProvider: at qbv.run(PG:166)
    E DialerMddCallerTagsConfigProvider: at qbv.run(PG:394)
    E DialerMddCallerTagsConfigProvider: at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
    E DialerMddCallerTagsConfigProvider: at qnh.run(PG:64)
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied

    E SensorService: Required app com.android.server.display.DisplayPowerController, uid 1000, pid 1750
    E minksocket: MinkIPC_QRTR_Service: client with node 1 port 4fc0 went down
    E minksocket: MinkIPC_QRTR_Service: client with node 1 port 4fc1 went down
    E minksocket: MinkIPC_QRTR_Service: client with node 1 port 4fc2 went down
    E Diag_Lib: [IMS_AP]"ims-rtp-daemon ims_rtp_qmi_handler_thread_func waiting on select thread>"
    E Diag_Lib: [IMS_AP]"ims-rtp-daemon ims_rtp_qmi_handler_thread_func waiting on select thread>"
    E minksocket: MinkIPC_QRTR_Service: client with node 1 port 4fc3 went down
    E Diag_Lib: [IMS_AP]"ims-rtp-daemon ims_rtp_qmi_handler_thread_func waiting on select thread>"
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E Orms_ManagerInner: cannot connect to orms core service!
    E DpcExtImpl[0]: execute mBlockReasonList.clear
    E ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER: Perflock resource SPECIAL_NODE - cpubw_hwmon_hyst_opt not supported
    E ANDR-PERF-RESOURCEQS: Failed to apply optimization [6, 3]
    E ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER: Perflock resource /sys/class/devfreq/soc:qcom,llccbw/bw_hwmon/sample_ms not supported
    E ANDR-PERF-RESOURCEQS: Failed to apply optimization [12, 3]
    E ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER: Perflock resource SPECIAL_NODE - llcbw_hwmon_hyst_opt not supported
    E ANDR-PERF-RESOURCEQS: Failed to apply optimization [12, 2]
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E cellularState[0]: - unhandledMessage: msg.what=4
    E OplusCustomizeRestrictionManagerService: getMobileDataMode error :s == null
    E ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER: Perflock resource SPECIAL_NODE - cpubw_hwmon_hyst_opt not supported
    E ANDR-PERF-RESOURCEQS: Failed to apply optimization [6, 3]
    E ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER: Perflock resource /sys/class/devfreq/soc:qcom,llccbw/bw_hwmon/sample_ms not supported
    E ANDR-PERF-RESOURCEQS: Failed to apply optimization [12, 3]
    E ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER: Perflock resource SPECIAL_NODE - llcbw_hwmon_hyst_opt not supported
    E ANDR-PERF-RESOURCEQS: Failed to apply optimization [12, 2]
    E netd : dispachCmd:oplusGetRtt
    E netd : handleGetRttCmd: netId = 100, uid = 10251
    E netd : dispachCmd cmd:oplusGetRtt result:139
    E netd : dispachCmd:oplusGetRtt
    E netd : handleGetRttCmd: netId = 104, uid = 10251
    E netd : dispachCmd cmd:oplusGetRtt result:0
    E IHansComunication: HANS printMessageBody: RCV message: type = 3,port = 86870,caller_pid = 1,caller_uid = 0,target_pid = 17334,target_uid = 0,pkg_cmd = -1,rpc = signal/-1
    E VendorNfcService: changeNfcStateByWirelessCharge: feature WIRELESS_CHARGING = true; mIsWirelessCharging: false; mIsReverseChargingSwitchOpen: false; mNfcWorkMode: 0; isOverSeaRegion() = true
    E Battery : ChargeProtectionUtils: mCanlendarTmp.isEmpty()!
    E TetherController: property_get sys.radio.data.modem_share_flag return 0, 1!
    E horae : 0: back:36374,frame:35546,front:37482, 6, +(2501), 1 ,36800,38000,37000,38000,39983
    E netd : dispachCmd:oplusGetRtt
    E netd : handleGetRttCmd: netId = 100, uid = 10251
    E netd : dispachCmd cmd:oplusGetRtt result:0
    E netd : dispachCmd:oplusGetRtt
    E netd : handleGetRttCmd: netId = 104, uid = 10251
    E netd : dispachCmd cmd:oplusGetRtt result:0
    E netd : dispachCmd:oplusGetRtt
    E netd : handleGetRttCmd: netId = 100, uid = 10251
    E netd : dispachCmd cmd:oplusGetRtt result:0
    E netd : dispachCmd:oplusGetRtt
    E netd : handleGetRttCmd: netId = 104, uid = 10251
    E netd : dispachCmd cmd:oplusGetRtt result:0
    E TetherController: property_get sys.radio.data.modem_share_flag return 0, 1!
    E OplusArpPeer_euclid_psw: ARP read failure: android.system.ErrnoException: read failed: EAGAIN (Try again)
    E OplusArpPeer_euclid_psw: OplusArpPeer close
    E VendorNfcService: changeNfcStateByWirelessCharge: feature WIRELESS_CHARGING = true; mIsWirelessCharging: false; mIsReverseChargingSwitchOpen: false; mNfcWorkMode: 0; isOverSeaRegion() = true
    E Battery : ChargeProtectionUtils: mCanlendarTmp.isEmpty()!
    E netd : dispachCmd:oplusGetRtt
    E netd : handleGetRttCmd: netId = 100, uid = 10251
    E netd : dispachCmd cmd:oplusGetRtt result:0
    E netd : dispachCmd:oplusGetRtt
    E netd : handleGetRttCmd: netId = 104, uid = 10251
    E netd : dispachCmd cmd:oplusGetRtt result:0
    E sensors-hal: handle_sns_client_event:86, pedometer_minute: report_ts=11,counter=0.000000 move_status =[SNS_CMC_STATIONARY] time_gap = 0 run_counter=0.000000 walk_counter=0.000000
    E AppOps : attributionTag not declared in manifest of com.oplus.exsystemservice
    E AppOps : attributionTag not declared in manifest of com.oplus.exsystemservice
    E TetherController: property_get sys.radio.data.modem_share_flag return 0, 1!
    E horae : 0: back:36164,frame:35033,front:36835, 6, +(3028), 1 ,36800,38000,37000,39000,39863
    E netd : dispachCmd:oplusGetRtt
    E netd : handleGetRttCmd: netId = 100, uid = 10251
    E netd : dispachCmd cmd:oplusGetRtt result:0
    E netd : dispachCmd:oplusGetRtt
    E netd : handleGetRttCmd: netId = 104, uid = 10251
    E netd : dispachCmd cmd:oplusGetRtt result:0
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E netd : dispachCmd:oplusGetRtt
    E netd : handleGetRttCmd: netId = 100, uid = 10251
    E netd : dispachCmd cmd:oplusGetRtt result:0
    E netd : dispachCmd:oplusGetRtt
    E netd : handleGetRttCmd: netId = 104, uid = 10251
    E netd : dispachCmd cmd:oplusGetRtt result:0
    E TetherController: property_get sys.radio.data.modem_share_flag return 0, 1!
    E VendorNfcService: changeNfcStateByWirelessCharge: feature WIRELESS_CHARGING = true; mIsWirelessCharging: false; mIsReverseChargingSwitchOpen: false; mNfcWorkMode: 0; isOverSeaRegion() = true
    E Battery : ChargeProtectionUtils: mCanlendarTmp.isEmpty()!
    E netd : dispachCmd:oplusGetRtt
    E netd : handleGetRttCmd: netId = 100, uid = 10251
    E netd : dispachCmd cmd:oplusGetRtt result:0
    E netd : dispachCmd:oplusGetRtt
    E netd : handleGetRttCmd: netId = 104, uid = 10251
    E netd : dispachCmd cmd:oplusGetRtt result:0
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E netd : dispachCmd:oplusGetRtt
    E netd : handleGetRttCmd: netId = 100, uid = 10251
    E netd : dispachCmd cmd:oplusGetRtt result:0
    E netd : dispachCmd:oplusGetRtt
    E netd : handleGetRttCmd: netId = 104, uid = 10251
    E netd : dispachCmd cmd:oplusGetRtt result:0
    E TetherController: property_get sys.radio.data.modem_share_flag return 0, 1!
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E VendorNfcService: changeNfcStateByWirelessCharge: feature WIRELESS_CHARGING = true; mIsWirelessCharging: false; mIsReverseChargingSwitchOpen: false; mNfcWorkMode: 0; isOverSeaRegion() = true
    E Battery : ChargeProtectionUtils: mCanlendarTmp.isEmpty()!
    E netd : dispachCmd:oplusGetRtt
    E netd : handleGetRttCmd: netId = 100, uid = 10251
    E netd : dispachCmd cmd:oplusGetRtt result:0
    E netd : dispachCmd:oplusGetRtt
    E netd : handleGetRttCmd: netId = 104, uid = 10251
    E netd : dispachCmd cmd:oplusGetRtt result:0
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E DpcExtImpl[0]: execute mBlockReasonList.clear
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E Proxy : Unsupported message id 2003
    E Proxy : Unsupported message id 2003
    E Proxy : Unsupported message id 2003
    E Proxy : Unsupported message id 2003
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E cellularState[0]: - unhandledMessage: msg.what=8
    E GestureMonitorController: updateGesturePhoneState no such gesture
    E GestureMonitorController: updateGesturePhoneState no such gesture
    E GestureMonitorController: updateGesturePhoneState no such gesture
    E GestureMonitorController: updateGesturePhoneState no such gesture
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E minksocket: MinkIPC_QRTR_Service: client with node 1 port 4fc4 went down
    E Diag_Lib: [IMS_AP]"ims-rtp-daemon ims_rtp_qmi_handler_thread_func waiting on select thread>"
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E msm8974_platform: platform_check_backend_tag_match: Invalid snd_device = voice-dmic-ef
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E DamilaCallUtils: isCallOnNr rat = 6
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbOpen failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: sysOpen failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: sharedImFd failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E MMListServiceParser: open file /proc/3732/cmdline err 13
    E d.calllogbackup: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x40000000
    E d.calllogbackup: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER: Perflock resource SPECIAL_NODE - cpubw_hwmon_hyst_opt not supported
    E ANDR-PERF-RESOURCEQS: Failed to apply optimization [6, 3]
    E ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER: Perflock resource /sys/class/devfreq/soc:qcom,llccbw/bw_hwmon/sample_ms not supported
    E ANDR-PERF-RESOURCEQS: Failed to apply optimization [12, 3]
    E ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER: Perflock resource SPECIAL_NODE - llcbw_hwmon_hyst_opt not supported
    E ANDR-PERF-RESOURCEQS: Failed to apply optimization [12, 2]
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER: Perflock resource SPECIAL_NODE - cpubw_hwmon_hyst_opt not supported
    E ANDR-PERF-RESOURCEQS: Failed to apply optimization [6, 3]
    E ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER: Perflock resource /sys/class/devfreq/soc:qcom,llccbw/bw_hwmon/sample_ms not supported
    E ANDR-PERF-RESOURCEQS: Failed to apply optimization [12, 3]
    E ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER: Perflock resource SPECIAL_NODE - llcbw_hwmon_hyst_opt not supported
    E ANDR-PERF-RESOURCEQS: Failed to apply optimization [12, 2]
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E IPCThreadState: attemptIncStrongHandle(85): Not supported
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E vxu : Uh oh! An open ClosingFuture has leaked and will close: {0}
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E TetherController: property_get sys.radio.data.modem_share_flag return 0, 1!
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER: Perflock resource SPECIAL_NODE - cpubw_hwmon_hyst_opt not supported
    E ANDR-PERF-RESOURCEQS: Failed to apply optimization [6, 3]
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER: Perflock resource /sys/class/devfreq/soc:qcom,llccbw/bw_hwmon/sample_ms not supported
    E ANDR-PERF-RESOURCEQS: Failed to apply optimization [12, 3]
    E ANDR-PERF-OPTSHANDLER: Perflock resource SPECIAL_NODE - llcbw_hwmon_hyst_opt not supported
    E ANDR-PERF-RESOURCEQS: Failed to apply optimization [12, 2]
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E SchedAssist: ofbSetSfMsgTrans pid(1419) failed with error=Permission denied
    E NhsManager: getLastLoc fail for GDPR!
    E NhsManager: getLastLoc fail for GDPR!
    E NhsManager: getLastLoc fail for GDPR!
    E NhsManager: getLastLoc fail for GDPR!
    E netd : dispachCmd:oplusGetRtt
    E netd : handleGetRttCmd: netId = 100, uid = 10251
    E netd : dispachCmd cmd:oplusGetRtt result:0
    E netd : dispachCmd:oplusGetRtt
    E netd : handleGetRttCmd: netId = 104, uid = 10251
    E netd : dispachCmd cmd:oplusGetRtt result:0
    E IHansComunication: HANS printMessageBody: RCV message: type = 3,port = 86870,caller_pid = 1,caller_uid = 0,target_pid = 17406,target_uid = 0,pkg_cmd = -1,rpc = signal/-1




Have you tried the same SIM in a different phone and it works? If so start by factory resetting this one and troubleshoot from there.

@ChanganAuto the Sims works in other phone. I may try wiping tomorrow, as a desperate try

How old is the SIM card? Does the other phone you have tested the SIM card in was also a new phone with 5G support? If not may be the SIM card is too old and is not compatible with 5G.
